# Unable to override method from base class from Java library in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to extend a class from a Java library and override the base method, but Eclipse keeps giving me errors even though the method signature is correct.

My code looks like this:

```
import someLibrary.ClassA
import someLibrary.TypeX
import someLibrary.TypeY
...
class MyClass extends ClassA {
     ...
     override def foo(s: TypeX, params: Array[String]): List[TypeY] = {
          ...
     }
}
```

The error I keep getting is:

> overriding method foo in class ClassA of type (x$1: someLibrary.TypeX,
>   x$2: Array[String])java.util.List[someLibrary.TypeY];  method foo has
>   incompatible type

Note that my method signature is exactly the same.

**EDIT:**
After reading Ren's answer here's how I fixed it:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
myScalaList.asJava
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that the original method is returning a java.util.List, while your override is returning a Scala list.